# How to show different groups in same matrix where no parent or child relationship

Tags: matrix, grouping, ssrs-2008-r2

I am tasked with reproducing a spreadsheet in an SSRS report to save hours of Excel spreadsheet work.  I have done all the calculations and got them into a single dataset however I am not able to work out how to display in the same table/matrix.
My spreadsheet looks like this:

[image: spreadsheet]

Column B is a text column used to describe what the figures in each group are showing.  Col C is 'Region' grouping.

I have got this far with my matrix - grouping by region and month. This gives me rows 3 to 8 incl of the spreadsheet.

[image: design view]

But I am not able to work out how to add the next group of data  (rows 9 to 12 in the spreadsheet) into the matrix. Each group of figures would use an expression to pull by a different field so only using single dataset:  I still want it to use the region and month exactly the same as the top group. There is no parent or child relationship between the labels in col B in the spreadsheet.

I have tried adding an adjacent group below but it is still trying to keep it as part of the top group.

Is this at all possible?
do I need to have 6 different matrix, placing them together and just hide the month names in the bottom 5?

This is an extract of the data results.  The top group counts the uniques customer id, the second group counts the unique sale id, the 3rd group totals the net sale value, the 4th group totals the profit value, the 5th group calculates the total sales and divides by the number of customers, the 6th group calculates the total sales and divides by the number of sales.

[image: query results]

Comment: If you can get all the data in a single dataset then you should be fine to do it in one go. Can you edit your question and show a sample of your dataset results (exactly as it comes from the dataset query) and then explain how you differenciate each group then I'll try to help.

Comment: Thank you @AlanSchofield I have amended my query as requested - it is a single dataset

Comment: Been away for a while. I'll try to look at this this evening but I would probably do all the work in SQL and let the report just dump the results. The cell formatting could be dynamic based on the group easily enough.

Comment: I have done the report with 6 separate tablix and amended the aggregate funtions within each tablix - does the job. Thank you all for your help

Comment: Sorry been stupidly busy at work. Got halfway thru writing it and then everything got urgent ! I might post an answer if I get time anyway as you may find it an easier approach in the future. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you will have to have 6 separate tablix and amend the aggregate function and field for each tablix

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I thought that might be the case.  Was just hoping that some super user would come up with some wizardry way of doing it.