# Hidden header row in multiple tablix causing white space

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, removing-whitespace

In my post yesterday I showed a spreadsheet that I am trying to re-create:
<[How to show different groups in same matrix where no parent or child relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62431581/how-to-show-different-groups-in-same-matrix-where-no-parent-or-child-relationshi)>

Following that post I have created an SSRS report placing multiple matrix directly underneath each other. I have placed them so that there is 0 points between each matrix. I have hidden the header row in all of the matrix's except the top one.
[image: design view]

Unfortunately that is causing white space between each matrix where I do not want any.  I want to replicate the spreadsheet  from my initial post.
[image: results]

I have found lots of posts but only 1 where it concerned hidden matrix header rows and that did not seem to have a conclusive answer:
<[hiding and removing white space of header in ssrs report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274855/hiding-and-removing-white-space-of-header-in-ssrs-report)>

Is there any way to get each matrix to roll up to directly underneath the matrix above so that there is no white space between them and the header is still hidden in each of the bottom matrix's?

Comment: Instead of hiding the header row, why not just delete it? Also, I hadn't read your previous question but I'm not sure why you could not get all the data in a single dataset an produce the report with a single matrix. I'll comment on your previous question later and ask for more info but I won;t be able to do anything until Tuesday next week.

Comment: Thank you @AlanSchofield - I am grateful for any help